# Return Javascript managed cookies programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, cookies, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to programmatically ping a website (through a console application) and return details of all the cookies being used by that site.

The following approach I'm using only captures those cookies managed through the header request and misses the ones set using Javascript:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)";
request.Method = "GET";

response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

foreach (Cookie c in response.Cookies)
{
   cookie.Add(c);
}
```

Can someone possibly provide suggestions to how this can be extended to include javascript configured cookies?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to get cookie values created and set by another site's client-side javascript?

Comment: Yes. I'm writing a crawler that automatically browses a set of sites and records which cookies they gather.

Comment: i guess if you just ping a website programaticaly , javascript doesnt get executed, so no javascript cookie is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just managed to achieve something close to what I wanted (still testing the solution, and it seems to be missing some tracking cookies from 3rd parties!). However what I did was use Selenium, and the Chrome Driver executable. What it does is open up an instance of chrome, navigates to the URL, and pulls back all the dynamically generated information, which can then be interrogated using C#. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure how much help this will be but...

You are asking if there is an easy way to get cookies that are created dynamically by client-side javascript and the answer is no, there isn't (unless I'm missing something).

Is there a harder way, maybe, like wrapping the .NET browser control, letting the javascript execute through automated web scripts and then scraping the DOM...  Doesn't sound like a good idea to me though.

Any other thoughts welcome.